# How to center text in a list in CSS?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have the following CSS list definition:

```
a {
    background-color: black;
    display:block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Which results in this kinds of buttons:

[image: List with big buttons and a link in it]

I would like the text to be right in the middle of those circles instead. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `span` an element.  Try this.

Working codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ePMdrL

```css
a{
  background:black;
  color:#fff;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block; 
  text-align:center; 
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  }
  
a span{
   position:absolute;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
```

```html
<a href="#"><span>Link</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of display:block; this:

```
a {
    /* display:block; <- delete this */
    /* put this instead */
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

reference material:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Flex

Answer (score 0):

You could use the line-height property. [Working Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wYmzGW).

```
.circle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom list style, for instance:

```
ul.leaf {
  list-style-image: url('/images/leaf_icon.jpg');
}
```